# TypeORM: How to partialy update given entity with query runner?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

If I want to partially update my user's name I can easily do this:

```js
await this.repository.save({ id: 1, name: 'john' });
```

But when I do it with queryrunner, It requires all field to exist and throws `missing following properties from type 'User'`

```js
await queryRunner.manager.save({ id: 1, name: 'john' }); // Error: Missing property
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the `save` operation will be transformed to `insert`,maybe you need checking sql executed.And also you can try this:

```js
await queryRunner.manager.update(User, 1, { name: "john" });
```

Comment: @omidh referenced from https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3772, I can not believe ```missing following properties from type 'User'``` is occured in ```update``` operation.Can u show sql transformed? And I think use ```save``` is a bad idea for ```update```, because typeorm always check the correspond record whether exist and then do ```update``` or ```insert```, that is costed.